# Skype for SalesForce Question

Tags: spring17

I am in the process of enabling Skype for Business in Salesforce. When I send someone a message, there is no notification within Salesforce that a message has been received. But if the user finds the senders name and presses the "Message" button, the window will appear and the message will then be visible. The recipient of the message gets a notification in Office 365 and on the Skype for Business App, but again there is nothing in Salesforce to indicate that a new message has been received.

I imagined when learning about Skype for Salesforce that when I sent a message in Salesforce that a window would appear within Salesforce for the user receiving a message (like any other chat program....). Then the 2 could continue the conversation without ever leaving Salesforce. This doesn't seem to be the case, unless I am missing something.

Why when I send someone a message in Salesforce using the window picture below, does the same window not appear for the recipient within Salesforce?

[image]

When using the Skype for Business App, it does notify you in the bottom right hand corner of the screen that you have received a message but the receiving party has to either:

- Use the notifying "Desktop app - Skype for Business"  to respond. Which works but seems counter intuitive to have to use 2 programs.

or

- After receiving a notification on Office 365 or Skype for Business app, Find the senders name in Salesforce, press the message button, and then the conversation can be continued on Salesforce.

I know there is some cool functionality coming to Skype for Salesforce in Spring 2017 but whats the point of it all if we have to use at a minimum 2 programs to make Skype for Business work?

**My questions:**

Is this problem due to a lack of permissions or is this a function that does not exist yet for Skype for Salesforce?

**If the functionality indeed does not exist yet...**

Is this functionality coming with the new update or can I expect to have the same problem after Spring 2017?